# How to escape space in file path in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which needs to go through files in a directory in an iOS device and remove files one by one.
To list files from command line I use the following command:

```
ios-deploy --id UUID --bundle_id BUNDLE -l | grep Documents
```

and to go one by one on each file I use the following for loop in my script

```
for line in $(ios-deploy --id UUID --bundle_id BUNDLE -l | grep Documents); do
     echo "${line}"
done
```

Now the problem is that there are files which names have spaces in them, and in such cases the for loop treats them as 2 separate lines.

How can I escape that whitespace in for loop definition so that I get one line per each file?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: you can add `IFS=$'\n'`  to make newlines the only separator before the `for` loop.

Comment: @Ardit That doesn't really work: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @Ardit, ...let's say the output returned contains the string `Documents/*.xyz`. If your `for line in $(ios-deploy ... | grep Documents)` is run with it and no `Documents/*.xyz` files exist matching the glob, your script will fail if `failglob` is active, or completely ignore the line if `nullglob` is active... and if any matches *do* exist, then you'll get back the list of matching files, not the literal output from `ios-deploy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solve your issue:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\n'
do
  echo "${REPLY}"
done < <(ios-deploy --id UUID --bundle_id BUNDLE -l | grep Documents)
```

Edit per [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) recommendation:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "${line}"
done < <(ios-deploy --id UUID --bundle_id BUNDLE -l | grep Documents)
```

Comment: Good answer overall. A few quibbles: `$'\n'` is the default value for `-d`, so it's not strictly needed. `REPLY` as a default destination is a bashism, so there's value to being in the habit of actually providing an explicit variable name.

Comment: Thank You for tips, agree and I added into answer.